# PIL problems: failed in loading any font library and using unicode

Tags: python, unicode, fonts, python-imaging-library

I newly installed PIL. But I find:

1. I can't load any font lib using
   "ImageFont.truetype("xxx.ttc", 50)"
   and the like.
2. When I render some text to image,
   and the text is unicode containing
   Chinese characters, I get
   UnicodeEncodeError like:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't encode character u'\u6211' in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

The problem script is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PIL import Image
import ImageFont, ImageDraw

text = sys.argv[1]
if not isinstance(text, unicode):
    text = text.decode('gbk')
filename = sys.argv[2]

image = Image.new("RGBA", (100, 100), (255,255,255))
usr_font = ImageFont.truetype("simsun.ttc", 50)  #In fact, it can't load any font lib.
d_usr = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
d_usr = d_usr.text((10, 10), text, fill = "blue", font=usr_font) #error when text is Chinese
image.save(filename)
```

My OS is Windows7, with Python 2.5 installed. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine on Ubuntu10.10 with python 2.6.6
Perhaps try using the absolute path to the tcc font?

This is the code that runs flawlessly:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Image
import ImageDraw
import ImageFont

ttfont = ImageFont.truetype ('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-microhei.ttc', 20)
text = u'我能有乾酪？'
image = Image.new ('RGB', (256, 128), 0xffffff);
ImageDraw.Draw (image).text ( (20, 20), text, font = ttfont, fill = (0, 0, 0) )
image.save ('chinese.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I find two errors I made: 1)I used a font which doesn't exist on my computer, or a name without correct path. 2)When a Unicode string composed of Chinese characters is to be rendered as image, a Chinese font is required! Otherwise PIL complains a UnicodeEncodeError, which may be misleading IMHO.